# how to use the MethodInvoker delegate to synchronize a call to a control's thread in cli c++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2005, command-line-interface

I have a c# but code and i need it in cli/c++, but always i get this errors

> "Error    2   error C2955: 'BaseLibCS::MethodInvoker' : use of class
>   generic requires generic argument list"
>
> "Error    4   error C2664:
>   'BaseLibCS::MethodInvoker::MethodInvoker(System::String
>   ^,...cli::array ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'GetNotifications ^const ' to 'System::String ^'"
>
> "Error    3   error C2102: '&' requires l-value"
>
> "Error    1   error C2872: 'MethodInvoker' : ambiguous symbol"

this is my c# code :

```
private void HandleFarmStateChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs<CFarm.FarmState> e)
        {
            if (control.InvokeRequired)
            {
                control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    HandleFarmStateChanged(sender, e);
                }));
                return;
            }

           //FarmStateStatusLabel.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(e.NewValue.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("       ");
        }
```

and this is my c++ code:

```
void GetNotifications::HandleFarmStateChanged(Object ^sender, ValueChangedEventArgs<CFarm::FarmState> ^e)
{
    if (control->InvokeRequired)
            {
                control->Invoke(gcnew MethodInvoker(this,&GetNotifications::HandleFarmStateChanged(sender, e)));
                //}));
                return;
            }

    Console::WriteLine(e->NewValue.ToString());
    Console::WriteLine("       ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After one day of researching i find the problem and it's because C++/CLI doesn't support anonymous delegates, that's an exclusive C# feature. You need to write the delegate target method in a separate method of the class. You'll also need to declare the delegate type, MethodInvoker can't do the job.

thiks a lot and have a nice day